# Rails STI model without a table on migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I've got a model, say `User`, and a model `Admin` which inherits from `User`. I have some code in `lib` folder which uses those two models. But if I install a new database and try to run the migrations rails crashes saying that there is no such model as `User`. Are there any best practices to bypass this error?

```
`Mysql2::Error: Table 'testing_interface_development.users' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `users`
/home/arthurborisow/Programming/my_project/test_interface/lib/active_record/timed_out_queries_hotfix.rb:9:in `query'
/home/arthurborisow/Programming/my_project/test_interface/lib/active_record/timed_out_queries_hotfix.rb:9:in `query_with_reconnect'
/home/arthurborisow/Programming/my_project/test_interface/lib/active_record/timed_out_queries_hotfix.rb:31:in `block in execute'
/home/arthurborisow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362-railsexpress@test_interface_install/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/home/arthurborisow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362-railsexpress@test_interface_install/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/arthurborisow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362-railsexpress@test_interface_install/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/home/arthurborisow/Programming/my_project/test_interface/lib/active_record/timed_out_queries_hotfix.rb:31:in `execute'
/home/arthurborisow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362-railsexpress@test_interface_install/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:259:in `execute_and_free'
/home/arthurborisow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362-railsexpress@test_interface_install/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:426:in `columns'
/home/arthurborisow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362-railsexpress@test_interface_install/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
/home/arthurborisow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362-railsexpress@test_interface_install/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `yield'
/home/arthurborisow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362-railsexpress@test_interface_install/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `columns'
/home/arthurborisow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362-railsexpress@test_interface_install/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:237:in `columns_hash'
/home/arthurborisow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362-railsexpress@test_interface_install/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:19:in `descends_from_active_record?'
/home/arthurborisow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362-railsexpress@test_interface_install/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:25:in `finder_needs_type_condition?'
/home/arthurborisow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362-railsexpress@test_interface_install/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:455:in `relation'
/home/arthurborisow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362-railsexpress@test_interface_install/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:37:in `scoped'
/home/arthurborisow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362-railsexpress@test_interface_install/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/querying.rb:9:in `where'
/home/arthurborisow/Programming/my_project/test_interface/app/models/admin.rb:15:in `<class:Admin>'
/home/arthurborisow/Programming/my_project/test_interface/app/models/admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'`
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error, passing `--trace` to `rake`?

Comment: What is the content of `lib/active_record/timed_out_queries_hotfix.rb` in your project? That seems to be where the error is originating, based on the back trace

Answer (score 3):

When setting up a completely fresh database (instead of upgrading your existing one), it is better to use `rake db:setup` to load the `schema.rb` file instead of running each migration in succession. This question explains the various **db** Rake tasks pretty well:

> [Difference between rake db:migrate db:reset and db:schema:load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload)

Comment: the same problem exists with `db:schema:load`

Answer (score 0):

```
   rake db:setup
```

Is the best option also,

You can also specify your migration version which do you want to migrate using below command:

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20080906120000
```