# rake db:migrate does not change table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, dbmigrate

I have a db with columns (name, path). Now I have a migration file that changes the columns to be (name, pathorig, pathjson, scramble).

Doing `rake db:reset` and `rake db:migrate` doesn't update the table. Why can this happen?

my migration file:

```
class CreateUploads < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :uploads do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :pathorig
      t.string :pathjson
      t.string :scramble

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The schema.rb file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131029072745) do

  create_table "uploads", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "path"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Difference between rake db:migrate db:reset and db:schema:load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload) has a great explanation of what the various `rake db:*` commands do.

Because `rake db:reset` performs a `db:schema:load`, it's loading the old columns from your table, rather than calling `db:migrate`, this is why your migration isn't being run.

Consider writing a migration that changes the names of those columns, rather than re-creates an existing table, or manually run `rake db:drop; rake db:create db:migrate`