# Rails 4 SQLite3::SQLException error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I have a devise User model which I want to add a admin boolean field so I ran

**rails generate migration add_admin_to_users admin:boolean** which created the following migration

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  add_column :users, :admin, :boolean
 end
end
```

However when I run rake db:migrate I keep getting the following error

**SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "admin" boolean/home/notebook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'**

I have tried to rake db:migrate VERSION=0 to rollback to the beginning and redone rake db:migrate again but I keep getting the same error

Here is my user model migration file

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table(:users) do |t|
  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0, :null => false
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  ## Confirmable
  t.string   :confirmation_token
  t.datetime :confirmed_at
  t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0, :null => false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # t.datetime :locked_at
  t.timestamps
end

add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
# add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
end
end
```

My db/schema.rb file is as follows:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140217093954) do
  create_table "entities", force: true do |t|
   t.string   "entity"
   t.string   "genre"
   t.string   "url"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
end

   add_index "entities", ["entity"], name: "index_entities_on_entity", unique: true
```

end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your development database is not in sync with the schema (or what you think the schema is). Running database migrations is intended for incremental changes and not intended to be be a way to rollback the database and run from the first migration. For this you want to use `rake db:reset`, which will drop the database and load the schema from db/schema. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload) has a good overview of the different database rake commands.

Comment: I've tried that too and then run rake db:migrate but I keep getting the same error

Comment: @Mutuma does your db/schema file have a users table in it?

Comment: I have like 13 models and my schema file indicates only one model which I had scaffolded but when I deleted the scaffold nothing in the schema changed. Let me post the schema.rb file

Comment: looks like you didn't run some of the migrations. What happens if you do "rake db:drop && rake db:migrate"?

Comment: I've just dropped the db and migrated the migrations and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Your database has not `users` table, you need to create `users` table first:

```
rails g migration create_users
```

And put that migration before the one you are trying to run now, i.e. changing its timestamp.

An easier option is to add in your current file:

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :users
  add_column :users, :admin, :boolean
 end
end
```

Whatever of the solutions you apply, you have a problem with the order of your migrations, search inside migrate folder for a migration that actually creates `users` table.

Comment: I created a Users table using the command rails g model Users which created a users table

Comment: please post migration file creating that table, that way we can be sure migration exists.

Comment: I have a had added a username field to the same table using a similar command only that I used username instead of admin and string as a field type and it worked perfectly

Comment: problem could be the timestamp of migrations, check that number in file `xxx_create_users` is greater than `xxx_add_admin_to_users`, `xxx` are the numbers

Comment: The file name of the admin migration is 20140223152952_add_admin_to_users.rb and that of the user model is 20140211193312_devise_create_users.rb