# heroku deployment error ruby on rails undefinedtable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, undefined

I am deploying my rails app for the first time and I got the following error:

> Migrating to Changetimezone (20140605033929)
>   == 20140605033929 Changetimezone: migrating ===================================
>   -- change_column(:opportunities, :updated_at, :date) PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "opportunities" does not exist :
>   ALTER TABLE "opportunities" ALTER COLUMN "updated_at" TYPE date rake
>   aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later
>   migrations canceled:
>
> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "opportunities" does not exist

Here is my opportunities model:

```
class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save :check_for_nil,:calculate_derated_value
has_many :updates, dependent: :destroy
has_many :activities, dependent: :destroy   
has_many :contacts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :links, dependent: :destroy
```

Clearly, it has associations. I'm not sure why the complaint is that it doesn't have associations... all the models that belong to it have a :belongs_to opportunities declaration

I'm at a complete loss of what might be going on. I've tried searching but I can't find any solutions that fix this exact problem.. does anyone have any ideas??

Comment: Have you run $ heroku run rake db:setup  ? that one always gets me.

Comment: PERFECT!!! @steel could you explain to me why that works and/or had to be done??

Comment: Heroku loads your migrations, but doesn't run them until you tell it to. However, your app has become dependent on the existence of those tables. So you run the above code (a combo of rake db:migrate followed by rake db:seed) and Heroku then has the tables it needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could you explain to me why that works and/or had to be done??

**Databases**

When you deploy Rails into a `production` environment (local is `development`), it's recommended you set up another database to handle the `production` input from users.

The problem is running `rake db:migrate` does *not* work on both the local & production database simultaneously; only works on the environment the command is called.

This means if you're pushing your  code to `Heroku`, you need to ensure you've ran all the `migrations` for it; as without them, you won't have the required changes.

--

As per the comments, it seems calling `rake db:setup` worked for you too. I'm not sure why this would work over the migrations (as [`rake db:setup`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload) just sets up the dbs as per the `schema` file):

**[Difference between rake db:migrate db:reset and db:schema:load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload)**

> - **db:migrate** runs (single) migrations that have not run yet.
> - **db:create** creates the database
> - **db:drop** deletes the database
> - **db:schema:load** creates tables and columns within the (existing) database following schema.rb

- **db:setup** does db:create, db:schema:load, db:seed
- **db:reset** does db:drop, db:setup