# Rake db:migrate error after db:reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble with running rake db:migrate and I get an error even after rake db:reset, and it says to run rake db:migrate and has the same error. What can I do to make it work and have the migration go through

```
SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "username" varchar(255), "password_digest" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) /Users/alextuazon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/Users/alextuazon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/Users/alextuazon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/Users/alextuazon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/Users/alextuazon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:334:in `block in execute'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `rake db:drop` to drop the tables and then `rake db:migrate` to create them and all the other stuff your migrations do.

*EDIT*: Additionally, reading [Difference between rake db:migrate db:reset and db:schema:load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload) the answers to might be helpful

Comment: so would i have to do the whole migration process again?

Comment: @user3817684 Yes - if you dont want to run migrations and only restore to the schema, do: `db:reset` which according to the SO Q&A I linked to, "does db:drop, db:setup"