# Create DB in production environment in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, schema, production-environment

I have searched for how to create db in production environment for rails and got 2 answers. Now I am confused with those answers.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create db:schema:load
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
```

What is the difference between these two? What does this schema means?

Why do we need `db:schema:load`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between rake db:migrate db:reset and db:schema:load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create` would create the database for the `production` environment,

whereas

`RAILS_ENV=production rake db:schema:load` would create tables and columns within the  database according the `schema.rb` for the `production` environment.

```
task :load => [:environment, :load_config] do
  ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.load_schema_current(:ruby, ENV['SCHEMA'])
end

task :create => [:load_config] do
  ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.create_current
end
```

Take a look at [this file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L21) for complete info on the topic.