# best way to add categories to database

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm looking for the best/most efficient way to add categories that save to a database.  I've created the category model with a name column.  I generated the controller.  My first thought was to just enter the categories directly into the controller since I will be the only one that can create, edit, and destroy them.  This is what it looked like:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

def women 
end

def kids
end

def babies
end

def home_decor
end

end
```

Fine, but that doesn't save to the db and since I'd like to associate these categories w/ products later I need it to save to the db.  I could create these categories directly in console, but I'm not sure if when I push to production (on Heroku) how to create them again (and that seems a little tedious).

The other option I have is to create a form to create the categories and only give access to an admin.

Am I missing something?  Is there a more efficient way to do this or is the admin route the best way to handle it?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget that controller. What you are looking for is in `db/seeds.rb`. It's just a script where you place the default content of your database. So in your case you'll need to put the following:

```
Category.delete_all # For avoiding duplicate content

Category.create!({id: 1, name: 'women'}) # Use create! so you'll know if there is any errors
Category.create!({id: 2, name: 'kids'})
# etc...
```

Then just run the script for placing that content in the db:

```
rake db:seed
```

And in heroku:

```
heroku run rake db:seed
```

Comment: Thanks Mario.  It worked great on dev, but I'm having problems w/ it on heroku due to another error.  Is there a way to view the Heroku database, maybe something similar to the sqlite browser?

Comment: What problem exactly? You could run `heroku run rails console`. Did you migrate your database on heroku?

Comment: I get this error message 

'rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: admin'

I had a user in seeds.db that had admin status but I had not created that table in the db for users.  So I created the table for admin and still got the error message.  I reset the db too and tried the heroku run rake db:seed again and same thing.  I then tried to delete that user from my seeds.db and reset but still getting same error message.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Try with `heroku run rake db:migrate` to see if it helps

Comment: heroku run rake db:migrate works fine, but after when I try to do heroku run rake db:seed I get same error message.  When i do run rake db:migrate, does it include the seed or are they separate?  Thanks!

Comment: They're different. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10302357/2273578) sums up what you need to know about running those commands. I need more info about your schema and/or models to see what is going on...

Comment: Thanks again.  I just added the schema to the original question.  I appreciate the help.  If there is any other model info you need please let me know.  This is so frustrating.

Comment: Well, it works now.  Not sure what I did differently, but it's working.  Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64813/discussion-between-mario-perez-and-kelly).