# Ruby-on-Rails Tutorial Trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, dbmigrate

I am new to both Ruby and Rails. So this may be an easy fix. I'm sorry if it is.

I recently installed Ruby-on-Rails and started following the tutorial on [rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) which shows how to make a simple blog. Everything was running fine until I got to section 5.5. I went to run db:migrate and it gave me an error.

```
|D:\Documents\Programs\Ruby\blog>rake db:migrate
== 20141216061542 CreateArticles: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:articles)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "articles" already exists: CREATE TABLE "articles" ("id" INTEGER 
PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "title" varchar(255), "text" text, "created_at" datetime,
 "updated_at"
 datetime) D:/Documents/Programs/Ruby/blog/db/migrate/20141216061542_create_articles.rb:3:in 
`change
'
C:in `migrate'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: table "articles" already exists: CREATE 
TABLE
 "articles" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "title" varchar(255), "text" text, 
"created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime)
D:/Documents/Programs/Ruby/blog/db/migrate/20141216061542_create_articles.rb:3:in `change'
C:in `migrate'
SQLite3::SQLException: table "articles" already exists
D:/Documents/Programs/Ruby/blog/db/migrate/20141216061542_create_articles.rb:3:in `change'
C:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I fired up the server to see what it would show and it gave me this:

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

It's been doing this ever since. I have tried starting over by deleting the project.(not entirely sure if that was a good move.) I have tried looking over the code. Nothing I have tried has given me any hints on what to do.

Is there any way to get rid of these errors?

Thank you in advance.

---

EDIT:
I tried to reset the database with 'rake db:reset', but it just gave me this:

```
|D:\Documents\Programs\Ruby\blog\app\views\articles>rake db:reset
(in D:/Documents/Programs/Ruby/blog)
Permission denied @ unlink_internal - D:/Documents/Programs/Ruby/blog/db/development.sqlite3
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1460:in `unlink'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1460:in `block in remove_file'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1468:in `platform_support'
...
rake aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - 
 D:/Documents/Programs/Ruby/blog/db/development.
sqlite3

Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I shortened it for readability.

And here is my create_articles migration file:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: instead of deleting your project, you can simply reset your db as Syed suggested

Comment: show your CreateArticles migration file

Comment: the problem might be in your db configuration file

Comment: I don't really know enough about how rails works to know what to look for. Are there any resources that might help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already created that particular table. Try this from your terminal:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Or:

```
rake db:reset db:migrate
```

So basically, you will start your database from scratch, which will avoid the current error.

Note that for new migrations, you only run the 'rake db:migrate' command otherwise your existing data will be lost.

Later on if you come across this problem in a production environment, ensure that you do 'something else' - surely you wouldn't want to sacrifice your production database data.

Comment: you can simply do: `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` or `rake db:reset db:migrate`. No need to reload rake every task

Comment: Ok +1 for the solution. You should probably explain why this will help him. Because it sure isn't a solution for a production environment :)

Comment: @SyedHumzaShah actually rake db:reset will be enough. It does db:migrate by itself

Comment: @railsr, I think db:reset loads the existing schema - it doesn't run pending migrations.

Comment: @railsr, true, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload

Comment: I tried using 'rake db:reset', but it gave me a new error. I'll edit it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well It seems obvious, you already have table articles, and you are trying to create a new one.

Two options:

- comment migration with articles do rake db:migrate, uncomment for other environment (if any)
- clear database and run migrations again.

Add create_articles to your question as well, could help resolving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the db

```
rake db:drop
```

And Migrated it once again

```
rake db:migrate
```

You have already create articles tables. So you need to drop it and migrate it once again.