# My database doesn't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm doing rail for begineer. I create the model Post with a title as string and body as text area. After that, I forgot to add new element in the form which is sub body

So,I add the sub body in 20150120154140_create_posts.rb and schema.rb as shown below

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
 create_table :posts do |t|
   t.string :title   
   #Add code below
   t.string :subbody
   t.text :body
   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

This is my schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150122040119) do

 create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "subbody"
  t.text     "body"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

After I add it , I write rake db:reset on terminal.

When I checked the db in IRB, Its shown in the table.

After I modified the views for createing new Post and submit it's doesn't save it.

Checked in IRB, its said nil at subbody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rake db:reset` doesn't run the migrations. You'll need to `rake db:migrate:down` followed by `rake db:migrate`. That should work as long as this is your newest migration. For more info, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload).