# Running rake db:setup removes all my users data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rake, scaffold

Within my ruby on rails application I have the seeds file, which contains data on the users such as:

```
User.create(:password => "jb", :password_confirmation => "jb", :role => 'admin', :first_name => "Joe", :last_name => "Bloggs",  :house_no => "1", :street => "A Street", :town => "A Town", :postcode => "ABC1 2DE", :email => "anemail@anemailaddress.co.uk")
```

But when I run `rake db:setup` it removes all the users data that I have entered into the database through the application (which is fine and expected) but does not enter the users data from the seeds.

I'm not sure if this makes a difference but I recently did three consecutive scaffolds.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `rake db:seed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking to do a `rake db:seed`.  Here is a good explanation of the other db rake tasks [Difference between rake db:migrate db:reset and db:schema:load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload)

Answer (score 1):

`db:seed` runs the db/seed.rb file

`db:schema:load` loads the schema into the current env's database

`db:setup` runs both  `db:schema:load` and `db:seed`