# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound / Couldn't find Maker with 'id'=1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I might've erased my user information (:maker_id, :name, and :password) when I did rake db:reset in terminal, so now going to 'localhost:3000' '/' gives me this error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PagesController#home
>
> Couldn't find Maker with 'id'=1
>
> Extracted source (around line #7):
>
> > 6  def current_user
> >
> > 7    @current_user ||= Maker.find(session[:maker_id]) if session[:maker_id]
> >
> > 8  end
> >
> > 9  helper_method :current_user

My application controller has:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= Maker.find(session[:maker_id]) if session[:maker_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user

  def authorize
    redirect_to '/' unless current_user
  end

end
```

My pages controller has an empty

```
def home
end
```

My pages home.html.erb view has:

```
<div class='text-center'>
    <h1>Welcome to venture</h1>

    <br><br>

    <%= link_to "Signup", '/signup', class: 'btn btn-success' %> or
    <%= link_to "Login", '/login', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
</div>
```

My layouts application.html.erb view has:

```
<body class="containter">

  <div class='pull-right'>
    <% if current_user %>
      Logged in as <%= current_user.name %> | <%= link_to "Logout", '/logout' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Signup", '/signup'%> or <%= link_to "Login", '/login' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <h1><%= link_to 'venture', '/' %></h1>

  <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
    <div class="alert alert-info fade in">
      <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
      <%= message %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<%= yield %>

</body>
```

It used to work before the db:reset which runs db:drop db:setup I believe. Usually I would just create users through the signup page but now I cannot get there.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

These records are not available any more - when `db:drop` was executed, all of them have been removed. The operation can not be `undone` and at the moment the only options you have is to restore db either manually or automatically if you have access to its backup.

Answer (score 0):

Run rake db:setup to recreate your database. Then create a new user.

Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload) to see the differences between various `rake db` commands