# Rails UnknownAttributeError when raking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Within seeds, I have created the following;

```
post = Post.create(
     title: Faker::Lorem.sentence(20),
     content: Faker::Lorem.paragraph,
     publish: true,
     administrator: administrator)

tag = Tag.create(name: Faker::Lorem.words)

post_tag = PostTag.create(post: post, tag: tag)
```

Then, within terminal i tried to "rake db:reset" and it is not working and showing the following error;

```
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0049s
 rake aborted!
 ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'publish' for Post.
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-    4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:59:in `rescue in  _assign_attribute'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord- 4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `each'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:566:in `init_attributes'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:281:in `initialize'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in `create'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/Desktop/PROJECT/RAILS-BLOG/-t/db/seeds.rb:13:in `<top  (required)>'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
 /Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:183:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:142:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 NoMethodError: undefined method `publish=' for #<Post:0x007f98d0073d00>
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activemodel-4.2.5.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `public_send'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `each'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:566:in `init_attributes'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:281:in `initialize'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in `create'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/Desktop/PROJECT/RAILS-BLOG/-t/db/seeds.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:183:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/laurenwoodhams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:142:in `block (2 levels) in <top   (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Could you please advise why it may be pushing this error?

Thank you

Comment: Check if `publish` column is added to your DB table? You can check the same by looking at the `schema.rb` file.

Comment: What does the migration for Post look like?  Or specifically, what does the migration that gives Post the "publish" attribute look like?

Comment: @ArupRakshit thank you, i checked my schema file and found a mistype. I had typed "pubblish" instead of "publish".

Answer (score 0):

> Then, within terminal i tried to "rake db:reset" . . .

Try running:

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:reset
```

Your `Post` object doesn't have a `publish` attribute according to your database (for whatever reason).

When you run `rake db:reset` new migrations do not get, 'migrated.'  Instead it loads the schema (that will not include migrations that were not migrated).

---

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10302357/1026898