# rails db:migrate vs rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rake

I noticed that when generating data migration in Rails 5, some people use `rails db:migrate` over `rake db:migrate`. Can someone explain the difference between the `rails` and the `rake` command in database migration? Does it mean the `rake` command is obsolete in Rails 5?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Rails core team decided to have consistency by enabling rails command to support everything that rake does. See PR [Implement rake proxy for rails cli #22288](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22288)

For example, in Rails 5, commands like `db:migrate`, `db:setup`, `db:test` etc., which are part of the rake command in Rails 4, are now being supported by the rails command. However, you can still choose to use rake to run those commands similar to how they were run in Rails 4. This is because the Rails community has introduced Rake Proxy instead of completely moving the command options from Rake to Rails.

What happens internally is that when `rails db:migrate` command is executed, Rails checks if `db:migrate` is something that rails natively supports or not. In this case, `db:migrate` is not natively supported by Rails, so Rails delegates the execution to Rake via Rake Proxy.

If you want to see all the commands that are supported by Rails in Rails 5, then you can get a long list of options by executing `rails --help.`

Comment: Any idea if there is a way to use the new syntax in a Rails 4 project?

Comment: @GregBlass You can includes module of rails 5 in to rails 4 to use it. but i don't think so you 
can use rails 5 syntax .

Comment: Rails 6 deprecates the rake-commands; At least some of them; `rake dev:cache`, `rake notes` and `rake routes`. They will be removed in Rails 6.1