# bundle vs bundler / bundle vs bundle install

Tags: bundler

1. What is the difference between the `bundle` & `bundler` commands?
2. What is the difference between `bundle` & `bundle install`?
3. If there're no differences, why have multiple commands that do the same thing?

Answer (score 81):

1. The executables [`bundle` & `bundler` have the same functionality](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/commit/2894378f018af36c9f0682f7032e934b76edc29f) and therefore can be used interchangeably. You can see in the [`bundler/exe`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/tree/master/exe) directory that the `bundler` executable just loads the `bundle` executable. It seems to me that the `bundle` command is more commonly used than the `bundler` command.
2. The commands `bundle` & `bundle install` also have the same functionality. `bundle` uses [Thor](http://whatisthor.com/), and [`bundle`'s default task is `install`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/commit/eea62b3f3eb76f50c08e2513e4b069dc3bb8ce2c). Also, `bundle i` does the same thing as `bundle install` because [`bundle`'s task `i` is mapped (aliased) to `install`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/commit/91794123f842d3fd439a75a43da7e341f8e0cde3).
3. That's a GREAT question. :-) Ruby tends to follow the [Perl programming motto: "There's more than one way to do it."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) I tend to prefer the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) principle: "There should be one—and preferably only one—obvious way to do it." I think the latter principle caters to the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and tends to help [keep things simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Overall however, I still tend to prefer to program in Ruby (especially when building HTTP-based RESTful APIs, for which I use [Rack](http://rack.github.io/)). I think Ruby is simple, elegant, and readable. Perhaps Ruby would be even better if it took on Python's stance regarding this issue.

Comment: Kinda reminds of rails and rake in the latest versions of rails (5.x) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403533/rails-dbmigrate-vs-rake-dbmigrate. As a newcomer to Ruby and RoR, one command is easier to learn.

Comment: `bundle` and `bundler` can be used interchangeable … unless for some reason your system ends up with one version of `bundle` and an incompatible version of `bundler`. Hours of debugging fun ‍♂️