# gem not installing bundler properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install `bundle` v. 1.5.2 and I'm having some trouble getting the correct version. Strangely, when I use `gem` to install bundler, I get two different versions for `bundle` and `bundler` even though [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43299367/3854235) SO answer says they should be the same. Here are a few commands that show the odd behavior:

```
$ which bundle
$ which bundler
$ gem install bundler -v 1.5.2
Fetching: bundler-1.5.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.5.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.5.2...
Building YARD (yri) index for bundler-1.5.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.5.2...
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.5.2
$ bundler -v
Warning: No private key present, creating unsigned gem.
Warning: No private key present, creating unsigned gem.
Warning: No private key present, creating unsigned gem.
It's recommended to use Bundler through 'bundle' binary instead of 'bundler'
Bundler version 1.16.2
$ which bundler
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@my-gem-set/bin/bundler
$ which bundle
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@my-gem-set/bin/bundle
```

Any ideas why I get different versions for `bundle` and `bundler`?

Comment: What are the outputs of the `which` calls after installation?

Comment: They point to the same directory. I'll update the question to include it.