# How can I fix a typo in data migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing the Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails Tutorial, and ran into this problem at the end of Chapter 11.

I did a migration to add `activation_digest`, `activated`, and `activated_at` columns to my data model.

```
$ rails generate migration add_activation_to_users \
> activation_digest:string activated:boolean activated_at:datatime
```

As you can see, I wrote `datatime` instead of `datetime`.
Now my migration file looks like this:

```
class AddActivationToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :activation_digest, :string
    add_column :users, :activated, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :users, :activated_at, :datatime
  end
end
```

Can I simply fix this error by editing the migration file? Or should I re-run the migration at the command line? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you already run the migration?

Comment: I did run the migration already, should have specified that in the post, sorry!

Comment: Did you run the _migration_ (`rake db:migrate`)? And it completed successfully?

Comment: I did, and I didn't have any reason to think it did not complete successfully, but it's possible I wasn't looking close enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rake db:rollback
```

will rollback the migration, then you can fix the typo and run

```
rake db:migrate
```

again to re run the migration.

Comment: Essentially correct, but if they are using a later version: it's:

`rails db:rollback` and `rails db:migrate`.

Corrected to say whichever command they are using is the best.

Comment: Really? I still use `rake`

Comment: According this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403533/rails-dbmigrate-vs-rake-dbmigrate), it seems like `rails db:migrate` is in fact delegated to `rake db:migrate`. So, why is `rake db:migrate` "essentially correct" and not "correct"?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/onwards-to-rails-5-additions-changes-and-deprecations/ "Another cool feature of Rails 5 is that all `rake` commands now live in `rails` (for example, `rake db:migrate` becomes `rails db:migrate`)." Not mandatory yet (or ever?), but since this was confusing and apparently an unneeded distinction it's all `rails` now.

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly (and I may not be), it seems that rails is essentially *wrapping* rake tasks (via the `Rake Proxy`). So, IMO it's a little misleading to say that all rake commands now "live" in rails. Rake tasks live where they have always lived. I appreciate that this is meant to make things less confusing (and it may or may not, I don't know). I guess I don't see how that all makes the answer less correct. Perhaps less fashionable...

Comment: This fixed it. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the migration file before you run the migration.

Comment: Are you sure the migration ran successfully? With an invalid datatype `:datatime`, it should not have been able to run and you shouldn't have to rollback the migration. Rolling back undoes the last successful migration and I doubt that's what you actually want. You should be able to edit the migration file and try to run the migration again.