# What does `rails spec` do that `rspec` does not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

What is it that `rails spec` does, if anything, that `rspec` alone does not?

I was looking for a way to run only specific RSpec tests from the command line, and the only way I found requires running `rspec` directly (`rspec --tag focus ...`, not via `rails spec`. I could do that, but I'm concerned that maybe doing so bypassing some important setup or other functionality.

Comment: Did you mean `rake spec` instead of `rails spec` ?

Comment: `rake` would work, but I believe starting with Rails 5, `rails` is the preferred way to invoke `spec`, `db:migrate`, etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403533/rails-dbmigrate-vs-rake-dbmigrate.

Answer (score 3):

It seems it calls `rails test:prepare` before actually calling `rspec`:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake#L11

Comment: Marek, thanks. Are you pretty sure that this the exact difference, that is, there are no other differences?

Comment: I am not, to be honest. But most of the times, testing with `rspec` works as expected.