# What is the difference between rails and rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the difference between commands `rake` and `rails` in Ruby?

Which one is faster and why?

Comment: `rails task_name` is a wrapper around `rake task_name`. It's all about convenience, i.e. having one binary to handle several things. Personally, I dislike this "Swiss Army knife" approach. I use `rake` when I want to run a Rake task.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell which one is faster?

Comment: Can i track time for a task with both rails/rake commands?

Comment: You could use `time rails task_name` vs. `time rake task_name`, see [time(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time) – the difference is probably negligible.

Answer (score 4):

[`rake`](https://ruby.github.io/rake/) is a Make-like program implemented in Ruby.

`rails` is a web framework, which also has some rake tasks.

This means that you can have a ruby program with rake but without rails, but not the other way around.

By itself, rake will be faster because you don't need to load the whole rails application.

But when launching a rake task, it can have dependencies, for example the `:environment` dependency in a rails app, which tells rake to load the rails environment and quite a bit of your application depending on the current environment.

In this case, the initialization of a rake task may take as long as a rails command.

Please note that the actual task run needs also to be taken into account, it can be very short or take several minutes.

For example, `rake db:migrate`, which is a rails task available by default, runs the migrations on the database, which can be time-consuming if the database is already populated and/or you have a lot of migrations

Comment: Thanks, but i could not understand which one is faster in rails environment?

Answer (score 4):

The difference is in what binary is being called.

If you were to call `bundle exec which rake` within your Rails app root directory, you'd get something like `/home/[USERNAME]/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/bin/rake` and for `bundle exec which rails`, you'd get `/home/[USERNAME]/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/bin/rails`. From there you can `cat` (`cat /home/[USERNAME]/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/bin/rake`) both these paths and see similar code is being ran for each, but the end of the files is different.

rails

```rb
gem "railties", version
load Gem.bin_path("railties", "rails", version)
```

rake

```rb
gem "rake", version
load Gem.bin_path("rake", "rake", version)
```

Here they're both calling `load` on `Gem.bin_path` but with different arguments, which are attempting to load separate gems in. You can follow the code further by running a irb/pry/rails console, and setting up the needed `require 'rubygems'` and `version = ">= 0.a"`, then run `Gem.bin_path("railties", "rails", version)` and `Gem.bin_path("rake", "rake", version)` to see what the `load` is actually trying to run. I'll admit it'll become a bit of a rabbit hole before you come across the logic that eventually ends up identifying a rake task argument passed to `rails` and it proxy's it to Rake and stop there and defer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38403595/4010391) for the rest.

When `rails` is ran and passed arguments which were intended to be ran by `rake`, it will attempt to first find if it was an actual argument intended to be given to the `rails` command, determine that it wasn't, then attempt to run it as a `rake` command for you for overall naming simplicity added in by the Rails team in Rails v4.

So which is faster to run? `rake` for actual rake tasks, as it'll bypass the extra logic in needing to determine it was being passed `rake` arguments. But also `rails` specific arguments cannot be ran with `rake` e.g. `bundle exec rake generate` will not work (unless you have a `generate` task). If in doubt, run `bundle exec rails --help` and in at least Rails v5, it'll output which arguments are `rails` specific and which are `rake` specific.