# rake db:reset fails halfway through dropping databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

In an attempt to solve a NoMethodError I was having, I read somewhere that running `rake db:reset` may help fix the problem. I am new to Rails and made the mistake of doing this without knowing exactly what this would do. When I ran it, it successfully dropped my development database (PosgreSQL), but then it hit a fatal error with the following message:

```
Dropped database 'development'
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
Couldn't drop database 'test'
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tasks: TOP => db:drop:_unsafe
```

I tried manually dropping the test database and rerunning `rake db:reset`, however the same error occurred. So I lost the data I had in my development database and am stuck with nothing but an empty production database.

I realize that this can probably be fixed by editing the `pg_hba.conf` file, but my app is running on my school's high performance cluster (Linux VM) and I don't have write access for that file. What I don't understand is why it was able to drop my development database, but not the rest.

I still have my `seeds.rb` and `schema.rb` files, so would it be possible to rebuild my databases without messing things up further? Or is there some way for me to fix the problem directly affecting the reset command?

Comment: You may want see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem regarding the authentication failure. When I first set up my database over a week ago I had added `host:localhost` to my `database.yml` file to circumvent the same issue. However, I only added it for my development database because that was all I needed to access up until now. Adding `host:localhost` to the other two databases in the file has fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

`rake db:reset` runs `db:drop` and `db:setup`.  `db:drop` drops the database for the current RAILS_ENV.  If RAILS_ENV is not set, it will attempt to drop both the development and test databases.

Try setting the your RAILS_ENV before running:

`RAILS_ENV=development rake db:reset`

Comment: I tried it but I still get the same error as before.

Comment: Try `RAILS_ENV=development` not `RAILS_ENV=dev`