# Rails issue with seeding and reseting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reset

I'm inserting data to tables via `seeds.rb` and I want to delete them running `rails db:reset`, but I got an error:

> rails aborted!
>   ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError:
>
> Environment data not found in the schema. To resolve this issue, run:
>
> bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development

After running this I am able to run `rails db:reset` but the data are still in the tables.

Comment: `db:reset` does `db:drop` and  `db:setup`. Then `db:setup` does `db:create`, `db:schema:load` and  `db:seed`.  So the seeds are getting run again is my guess.  This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload

Comment: Please specify RoR version

Comment: the version in  5.1.6

Comment: just do rake db:drop first